# UI Charts - Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, google-earth-engine-python-api, chart

I am using GEE Python API. I want to create a time series chart but the documentation says:

> Caution: the ui.Chart widget is available for the JavaScript Code Editor API only.

How do we create in Python API, then?

Comment: Here is a Earth Engine Python tutorial that is focused on charting: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/time-series-visualization-with-altair

Comment: @JustinBraaten Thank you so much! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the chart feature is only available in Code Editor, but you can manipulate the data in GEE Python API and use external libs to deal with the data structure and visualization.